# Minipage inside framebox creates an undesired horizontal spacing

Tags: boxes, minipage

In the following MWE I'd like the second framebox to look the same as the first one (see the image below).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
\framebox[\width]{A frame.}\par
\framebox[\width]{
\begin{minipage}{4em}
A frame.
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any clue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _you_ added the space here `h]{ ` Either don't add that space (line break) or put a `%` there to hide it.

Comment: It is unrelated to `minipage` try editing your `\framebox[\width]{A frame.}` to have a space or newline  before the `A`

Comment: @matbator BTW, the space in the end (the don't care one) stems from the fact that you allocated a 4em-wide minipage, but your text doesn't span 4em.

Comment: Hi Henri, Thanks for the clarification. I knew for the 4em but do you know what should have been set to fit the frame ?